# Will wildcards work on objects?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use wild cards in a parameter? I have this code which repeats for the properties TextLine1,TextLine2, TextLine3, and TextLine 4. Is it possible to replace the number with a wildcard and so that i can pass the number based on user input.

TextLine1, TextLine2, TextLine3, and TextLine 4 are properties of the class ReportHeader.

```
 public Control returnTextLine(ReportHeader TextLineObj,int i)
    {

        System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTextLine = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        lblTextLine.Name = TextLineObj.**TextLine1**.Name;
        lblTextLine.Font = TextLineObj.**TextLine1**.Font;
        lblTextLine.ForeColor = TextLineObj.**TextLine1**.ForeColor;
        lblTextLine.BackColor = TextLineObj.**TextLine1**.BackgroundColor;
        lblTextLine.Text = TextLineObj.**TextLine1**.Text;
        int x = TextLineObj.**TextLine1**.x;
        int y = TextLineObj.**TextLine1**.y;
        lblTextLine.Location = new Point(x, y);


        return lblTextLine;
    }
```

Please Help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this can't be done.
What you can do however, is to extend the class representing `TextLineObj` with a `TextLines` property which is a `ReadonlyCollection`:

```
public class TextLineObj
{
    public ReadonlyCollection<TextLine> TextLines { get; private set; }

    public TextLineObj()
    {
        TextLines = new ReadonlyCollection<TextLine>(
                            new List<TextLine> { TextLine1, TextLine2, 
                                                 TextLine3, TextLine4 });
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
TextLineObj.TextLines[i].Name;
```

Comment: i'm getting error at the new keyword and also at { TextLine1, TextLine2, TextLine3, TextLine4 } saying "does not contain a definition for Add"   

 public ReadOnlyCollection<TextLine> TextLines { get; private set; } 
public ReportHeader()
        {
            TextLines = new ReadOnlyCollection<TextLine>{TextLine1,TextLine2};
        }

Comment: @NewBie: Updated my answer. Try again.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, it's not possible to use wildcards for referencing objects.

You should instead store a collection of the `TextLine` instances in `ReportHeader`. This way you can easily access each TextLine by index.

```
public class ReportHeader
{
    private TextLine[] textLines

    ...

    public TextLine[] TextLines
    {
        get { return this.textLines; }
    }

    ...
}

public Control returnTextLine(ReportHeader reportHeader, int textLineIndex)
{
    TextLine textLine = reportHeader.TextLines[textLineIndex];

    System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTextLine = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    lblTextLine.Name = textLine.Name;
    lblTextLine.Font = textLine.Font;
    lblTextLine.ForeColor = textLine.ForeColor;
    lblTextLine.BackColor = textLine.BackgroundColor;
    lblTextLine.Text = textLine.Text;
    int x = textLine.x;
    int y = textLine.y;
    lblTextLine.Location = new Point(x, y);

    return lblTextLine;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done via reflection, of course. But I suggest to use the solution proposed by Daniel.